# Compile error generating tye library when adding putter to and idl file and matching c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I am getting this error when I am adding something to my idl file.

1>midl\oleaut32.dll : error MIDL2020: error generating type library : LayOut failed : Ithis(0x80029C83)

If I comment this part out it compiles oK.

```
   [propput] IDLAPI This([in] IThis* thisIt);



  STDMETHOD(put_Board)( IThis* thisIt)
  {
    return S_OK;
  }
```

Any ideas?????? I have tried so many things to make sure it all matches OK.

what does this error mean

THanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to split `[propget]` and `[propput]` for the same property between two interfaces, one derived from the other? Such a construct is not representable in the TLB format, hence MIDL complains. You won't be able to pull this off; reconsider your design.

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks. I would have never thougth of that. I will just make them not a property.